# 8 byte value reversed in chunks of 4 bytes rather than on a per byte basis when pushed onto the stack

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, endianness

Consider the following two instructions:

```
movabs rax,0xc931db3146b0c031
mov QWORD PTR [rbp - 0x80], rax
```

After stepping through them in gdb, I use `x/2x $rsp - 0x80` to see what was just pushed onto the stack. The output is:

```
0x7fffffffdfe0: 0x46b0c031  0xc931db31
```

I expect to see the following output:

```
0x7fffffffdfe0: 0x31c0b046  0x31db31c9
```

On a little endian machine, the 8 byte value `0xc931db3146b0c031` should be stored in memory as `0x31 0xc0 0xb0 0x46 0x31 0xdb 0x31 0xc9`, right?

Then why is the value reversed in chunks of 4 bytes rather than on a byte by byte basis?

Comment: Because gdb un-reverses the dwords for you. Use `x/8bx` to see the actual bytes.

Comment: Ok, that works. Thanks, I was very confused!